# Does autolayout mean I don't need separate iPhone and iPad xibs?

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is a really simple question, but I can't find a clear statement yea or nay.  I'm converting an app to iOS7.  The current app has separate xibs for iPhone and iPad.  I see that autolayout can handle different size iPhone screens and device rotation in a simpler way than previous approaches.  But, does autolayout mean I no longer need separate xibs for each device?  My guess is yes, but the documentation and tutorials I've looked at don't explicitly say it's possible.  I'm using xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can mean that yes, but not necessarily..

Usually most developers will want to use the iPad's extra pixels for more than 'just draw all the same stuff as on iPhone, only bigger' but if that's all you need then you could do it all with a shared nib and autolayout or indeed with the older autoresizingmasks...

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much what I thought.

Comment: Indeed: Apps have been known to get rejected for having their iPad UI be just a stretched-out version of their phone UI. That said, there are lots of great ways to share nibs for parts of your UI between platforms using Auto Layout. For example, a split view or popover on iPad can contain something that'd be an entire screen on iPhone, and use the same nib.

Comment: Thanks @rickster this is a good comment, extra iPad UIKit elements like UIPopover and the split view controller are indeed designed to help recycle iPhone sized nibs